# Symmetric probability measure

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $\nu$ be a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ with
> >     $$
> > \nu((-\infty,t])=\nu([-t,\infty))~\forall~t\in\mathbb{R}.
> > $$
> >     Show that
> >     $$
> > \nu(B)=\nu(-B)~\forall~B\in\mathcal{B},
> > $$
> >     whereat $-B:=\left\{-x|x\in B\right\}$.

Is it enough to show that for a generator of $\mathcal{B}$? As such a generator we always use $\Sigma:=\left\{(a_i,b_i]: a_i\leq b_i, a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$.

What is the idea to start the proof with?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an *idea to start the proof with*.

Consider $\mathcal C=\{B\in\mathcal B\mid\nu(B)=\nu(-B)\}$ and $\mathcal L=\{(-\infty,t]\mid t\in\mathbb R\}$, then $\mathcal L\subseteq\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal B$ and your goal is to prove that $\mathcal C=\mathcal B$. Which properties of $\mathcal C$ would interest you to show that $\mathcal C=\mathcal B$, which you can prove?

Comment: If I got it right, you are using the "principle of good sets", which here means: Show that (1) $\mathcal{L}\subseteq\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$, (2) that $\mathcal{L}$ is a generator of $\mathcal{B}$ and (3) that $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then it follows $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{B}$. Right?

Comment: The only thing that's not totally clear to me is, how to show that $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_n\in\mathcal{C}$ if $(B_n)\in\mathcal{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$. I started with $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_n=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_i\setminus B_{i-1}, B_0:=\emptyset$ in order to get a disjoint union to use the $\sigma$-additivity of $\nu$: $\nu(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_n)=\nu(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_n\setminus B_{n-1})=\sum_{n\geq 1}\nu(B_n\setminus B_{n-1})=\sum_{n\geq 1}\nu(B_n)-\nu(B_{n-1}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\nu(-B_n)-\nu(-B_{n-1})=\ldots=\nu(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}-B_n)$. So the union is in $\mathcal{C}$, right?

Comment: Why is $\mathcal{L}\subseteq\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: This is the hypothesis you were given.

Comment: But its not so clear that every $L\in\mathcal{L}$ is in $\mathcal{B}$. I think I should show this by using $\mathcal{B}=\sigma(\Sigma)$, where $\Sigma:=\left\{(a,b], a\leq b\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$. Because in the reading we only had this, that $\mathcal{B}$ is generated by $\Sigma$. Then I only need to write $(-\infty,t]=\bigcup_{k\geq 1}(t-k,t]$ which is in $\sigma(\Sigma)=\mathcal{B}$. That $\nu((-\infty,t])=\nu([-t,\infty))$ is given, yes.

Comment: You are wondering whether an interval is a Borel set or not? Seriously...

Comment: No, thats not the point... but I thought I have to show that intervalls of the form $(-\infty,t], t\in\mathbb{R}$ is a Borel set, because in the reading, as I said, we only defined $\sigma(\Sigma)=\mathcal{B}$ and so I thought I have to show this!

Answer (score 0):

Let me give an answer to my own question, please have a look on it and comment below if it is right or not, thank you!

---

Set
$$
\mathcal{A}:=\left\{B\in\mathcal{B}:\nu(B)=\nu(-B)\right\},\\
\mathcal{C}:=\left\{(-\infty,t]:t\in\mathbb{R}\right\}
$$
By definition it is $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$. Moreover, it is $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$, because consider a $C\in\mathcal{C}$, i.e. $C=(-\infty,t], t\in\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
C=\bigcup_{i\geq 1}(t-i,t]\in\sigma(\Sigma)=\mathcal{B}, \Sigma:=\left\{(a,b]: a\leq b, a,b\in\mathbb{R}\right\}. 
$$
That $\nu(C)=\nu(-C)$ follows from the task.

Now show (1) that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and (2) that $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{B}$. Then it follows $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}$ and that's the issue.

ad (1):

(i): $-\emptyset=\emptyset, \emptyset\in\mathcal{B}\Rightarrow \nu(\emptyset)=\nu(-\emptyset)\Rightarrow\emptyset\in\mathcal{A}\Rightarrow\mathcal{A}\neq\emptyset$.

(ii): $B\in\mathcal{A}$, i.e. $B\in\mathcal{B}, \nu(B)=\nu(-B)$. Then of course $B^C\in\mathcal{B}$ and 
$$
\nu(B^C)=1-\nu(B)=1-\nu(-B)=\nu(-B^C)\Rightarrow B^C\in\mathcal{A}
$$

(iii): $(B_n)_n\in\mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{N}}$, i.e. $\nu(B_n)=\nu(-B_n), n\geq 1$. With $B_0:=\emptyset$ it is
$$
\nu(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_n)=\nu(\biguplus_{n\geq 1}B_n\setminus B_{n-1})=\sum_{n\geq 1}\nu(B_n\setminus B_{n-1})=\sum_{n\geq 1}\nu(B_n)-\nu(B_{n-1})\\=\sum_{n\geq 1}\nu(-B_n)-\nu(-B_{n-1})\\=\sum_{n\geq 1}\nu(-B_n\setminus -B_{n-1})\\=\nu(\biguplus_{n\geq 1}-B_n\setminus -B_{n-1})\\=\nu(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}-B_n)\\\Rightarrow \bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_n\in\mathcal{A}
$$
(it`s clear that $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_n\in\mathcal{B}$)

ad (2):

Show $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\sigma(\Sigma) (=\mathcal{B})$

"$\subseteq$": Show $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\sigma(\Sigma)$; I have shown that already above

"$\supseteq$": Show $\Sigma\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal{C})$

Consider $C=(a,b]\in\Sigma$, then
$$
C=(-\infty,b]\cap \underbrace{(a,\infty)}_{=(-\infty,a]^C}\in\sigma(\mathcal{C})
$$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\Box$